# Dotproduct with complex numbers

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following example code performing a dot product of two vectors with complex numbers.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import I
sp.init_printing()

b1 = sp.Rational(1, 2) * sp.Matrix([I, 1, 0, -I, 1])
v2 = sp.Matrix([2 * I, 1 + I, 0, 1 - I, 2 * I])

print(sp.simplify(v2.dot(b1)))
print(sp.simplify(sp.conjugate(v2.T) @ b1)[0])
```

The output is:

```
-1 + I
2 - 2*I
```

Apparently the dot method does not conjugate the first argument. But I don't like the second workaround. What is a clean way to calculate the dot product of two vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot product conjugating the first vector:

```
v1.H.dot(v2)
```

Conjugating the second:

```
v1.dot(v2.H)
```

Some people want the former, some the latter; SymPy does not take a position on the matter.

In your example:

```
print(sp.simplify(v2.H.dot(b1)))
```

H stands for Hermite conjugation.